# Using a foreach to split elements into their own vairable

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm currently working on a method to import a CSV into a database (custom method to also get a little more knowledge on C#) I've encountered the following problem.

I'm trying to insert a split string into a database, each value being inserted into a different column.

I currently have:

> ID   | ClientName    | ShopName    | Address   | PostCode    | ContactNumber

as my columns. ID being the identify and self increment

and my code is:

```
public void FileContents(string Str)
       // private System.Collections.Generic.List<Tuple<string,string,string,string,string>> FileContents(string Str)
        {
            int Counter = 0;
            //string QueryString = "INSERT INTO "
            string[] split = Str.Split(',');
            foreach (string Element in split)
            {
                Element.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' });
                Console.WriteLine(Element);

                Counter++;
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);


        }
```

Using the foreach loop seems to yield the correct resuls which look like:

> Mrs DummyName
>
> ShopName Place Holder
>
> Address Place Holder
>
> PostCode place holder
>
> ContactNumber Place Holder

which is as expected. The approach on how to insert each of those elements into the correct column eludes me. I considered using:

```
Console.WriteLine(split[0]);
```

But this does not yield exptected results. Expected being:

> ClientName Placeholder
>
> ClientName Placeholder

But instead yields:

> ClientName Placeholder #1
>
> ClientName Placeholder #2
>
> ClientName Placeholder #3
>
> Address Placeholder **of** ClientName placeholder 3

so it is not iterating through each of the client names without skipping to the address.

So, what would be the best way to get each of the elements in the foreach loop to then insert into the database?

Comment: @user2864740 Updated the question title for clarity

Comment: Did you get any joy with the below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a string is *immutable*, this line will not alter Element...

```
Element.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' });
```

You would need something like:

```
var newElement = Element.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' });
Console.WriteLine(newElement);
```

Without seeing the input, I'll assume you have a file...

```
var lines = new List<string>();

  lines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt"));
  foreach(var lineToSplit in lines)
  {
      string[] split = lineToSplit.Split(',');
      foreach (string element in split)
         {
            var curElement = element.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' });
            Console.WriteLine(curElement);
         }
  }
```

You could create a class

```
public class Clients
 {
   public string ClientName { get; set; }
   public string ShopName { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string PostCode { get; set; }
   public string ContactNumber { get; set; }            
 }
```

and then populate a list of clients...

```
lines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt"));
var clients = new List<Clients>();

foreach (var lineToSplit in lines)
{
    var split = lineToSplit.Split(',');
    clients.Add(new Clients
    {
        ClientName = split[0]
        //etc
    });
}
```

Comment: Even after doing this, there is still display issues when printing out each iteration of the foreach loop

Comment: Can you add an example of the data you're iterating over?

Comment: I've just seen this edit, it was a formatting problem with the CSV spreadsheet, there was new line breaks in the address column, removed the breaks but still there are problems. On the otherhand, I do not understand the get & set functions

Comment: @DarylGill, the `Get / Set` is to access the properties of the class, so you'd be better building a `List` of your class, and working with this.

Comment: If you are interested in the complications, I narrowed down the source of the problem thanks to another question here on stackoverflow. I'll link you to the solution

Comment: OK, add the link here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354065/file-readline-adds-line-breaks-to-csv

Comment: @DarylGill, that still wont fix you're issue since your `foreach` wasn't correct.