# File.ReadLine adds line breaks to CSV

Tags: c#, csv

I have been converting an exported document from outlook to CSV which will be used to be interpreted by C# for further manipulations. The problem arises when using:

```
    string path = @"Contacts.csv";
    Program Self = new Program();
    // Open the file to read from. 
    var ReadLine = File.ReadLines(path);
    foreach (string Line in ReadLine)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Line);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

To display the following data:

[image]

Which is not expected output, and after hitting a key to pass the `ReadKey` the rest of the data is displayed with the following: [image]
 (Blanked out contact Numbers)

When the CSV it's self does not contain line breaks (used replace function using CTRL+J to mimic line break and replace with nothing). The CSV Looks like:

[image]

There are no line breaks present, this problem persists throughout the document on some iterations but not others. So why is there new line breaks being added and being pushed to another iteration, so why is this occouring? I've exhausted possibilities which are within my skillset

---

I've tried forcefully removing new line breaks

```
string ToPrint = Line.Replace("\n"," ");
                Console.WriteLine(ToPrint);
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Which returns the same result & will be actively trying out other possible solutions and updating with what's been tried

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("\r\n");` will display *two* new lines, is that what you actually wanted?

Comment: Alos, can you show us what the original content of `Contacts.csv` look like? (The first 2 lines will be sufficient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the CSV file with Notepad++ and configure it to display white-space characters. You'll find something. Maybe the file just has very many spaces. They are displayed on the console as black. Maybe the line just wrapped.

Your code is fine. No obvious mistakes. And neither `ReadLines` nor `WriteLine` are broken.

Comment: Give me a few moments, I shall perform this and update

Comment: When opening up this document, there indeed is line breaks shown. Problem seems to be incorrect WSIWYG within Excel. Line breaks seems to be non-existent when looking at the cells but are present in notepad++

Comment: After removing the new line breaks inbetween the double quotes, the display within the console application is as expected.  This is something I would not have considered. Thank you